# Failing to use the TypeScript interfaces generated by cxml

Tags: typescript, xsd, xml-parsing

I'm using TypeScript to implement an API wrapper for a XML REST service. All requests and responses are described in a schema, and I was able to use [cxsd](https://github.com/charto/cxsd) and [cxml](https://github.com/charto/cxml) to generate appropriate TypeScript and JS definitions. But I'm puzzled by the code generated by cxsd. The example is [in the repo](https://github.com/charto/cxml/blob/master/test/xmlns/dir-example.d.ts), here's the simplified version:

```
interface _foo {
    a: string;
    b: bar;
}
interface foo extends _foo { constructor: { new(): foo } }
var foo: { new(): foo };

interface _bar { 
    c: string;
}
interface bar extends _bar { constructor: { new(): bar } }
var bar: { new(): bar };
```

What does `constructor: { new(): foo }` mean at all?

I need to actually create these objects myself to build the XML and send it to the API backend, but I'm not able to do this. Trying something like:

```
let obj: foo = {
    a: "Test1",
    b: {
        c: "Test2"
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
scripts/foo.ts (13,5): Type '{ a: string; b: { c: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'foo'.
  Types of property 'constructor' are incompatible.
    Type 'Function' is not assignable to type 'new () => foo'.
      Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature 'new (): foo' (2322)
```

How could I create these objects? The whole idea of using TypeScript here is to verify that they are 100% compatible to the original XSD schema.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the code you want

```
let obj: Foo = {
    a: "Test1",
    b: {
        c: "Test2"
    }
}
```

This is the type definition you need

```
interface Foo {
  a: string,
  b: {
    c: string
  }
}
```

> The whole idea of using TypeScript here is to verify that they are 100% compatible to the original XSD schema

You'll have to write it yourself. Or find a tool (which I don't think exists meeting your quality requirements aka one that **works**.)